# How create Bollinger Bands with infinidb

Tags: php, statistics, infinidb

Currently, I use InfiniDB with php trader extension (there is `trader_bbands` function which help), but I want to check that all final values of Bollinger lines are correct with sql solution.

Comment: You are using the PHP extension to generate the bands and they are stored in the DB?  And you want to verify those band values in SQL?  Or you want to verify the bands created by the extension are correct by running SQL on your data?

Comment: @mhoglan I want verify that bands created by extension are correct.